# Iphone: Combining PageControl and TextView scroll problem help

Tags: iphone

I used the PageControl sample app from apple to build an app. I am putting on each page a vertically-scrollable TextView that I made using IB and I can -on the simlulator- scroll the pages and scroll vertically the text in each page.

On the device I cannot do that. It seems like the TextView is in front and I can't scroll to the pages on the sides. If I touch a little corner where there is no textview then I can scroll to the next page.

How can I make it this work on the device too?

Answer (score 0):

You could be seeing the imprecision of finger touches on the device that you don't see with the mouse on the simulator. On the simulator, you can reliably hit targets just a few pixels wide. On the device you cannot.

To test, I would shrink the Textview down to a size where there is little possibility you can hit it accidentally.

Comment: Thanks TechZen but the TextView in fact stretches almost all the page because it's an app that displays the lyrics of one song (one song on each page)

Comment: You might try doing a dump of the view hierarchy to make sure all the views are where you think they are. If they are then you might have to rethink your design. If users can't reliably hit your interface elements then the design is useless.